# Minimum age in signed request

Tags: facebook, restrictions

Is there any documentation for user.age.min in the signed request? I would like to know which values user.age.min can have.

E.g. if I'm implementing age restriction due to alcohol content in Iceland, will I then know if the user is 20 years old or more? Will I know if a Canadian user is at least 19 years old? Will I know if a user in Qatar is at least 21 years old? And so forth...

Answer (score 2):

Just testet it with one of my accounts with a user 20 years old - the signed_request gave me a min age of 18 - and with another user account, over 80 years old - the signed_request gave me 21. I think you will need to ask for the user_birthday permission if you want to have it more precise.

**UPDATE:**
Facebook has updated its docs:

> The following table shows the values returned depending on the user's
>   age. Note: max will not be retured for any user who is 21 years or
>   older.
>
> ```
> Min   Max
> 13    17
> 18    20
> 21    max is not sent
> ```

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Thank you! That is the same behavior as for me in Sweden. This is still unusable until I know exactly how this feature works. Official documentation is essential.